# R lubridate Time Zone does not give correct conversion to UTC/Zulu time, adds +1 hour

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, lubridate, utc

I am trying to convert minutes from midnight (360 meaning 6 AM ) local ( I am in central time) to UTC/Zulu in the ISO 8601 format. However, the results adds +1 hour to the conversion ( 6 hours instead of 5). Why is it adding +1 hour/how to fix this issue? However, when I use Sys.time() it works and correctly adds 5 hours.

```
library(lubridate)
minutes_from_midnight <- 360
local_time <- force_tz(as_datetime(minutes_from_midnight*60), tzone = "America/Chicago")
zulu_time <- with_tz(local_time, tzone = "UTC")
iso_time <- format(zulu_time, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
print(paste("ISO 8601 format for 6 AM local time is", iso_time))
```

[1] "ISO 8601 format for 6 AM local time is 1970-01-01T12:00:00Z"

```
Sys.timezone()
```

[1] "America/Chicago"

HOWEVER,

when I try the following using system time, it works (correctly adds + 5 hours):

```
local_time1 <- Sys.time()
zulu_time1 <- with_tz(local_time1, tzone = "UTC")
iso_time1 <- format(zulu_time1, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
print(paste("ISO 8601 format for current local time is", iso_time1))
```

I expected to add +5 hours instead the conversion adds +6 hours for minutes from midnight but not when using sys.time().

Comment: When you do `as_datetime(minutes_from_midnight*60)` this creates a time on 1st Jan 1970. This is in a different daylight savings time from summer (as it currently is).

Comment: oh, I see. I don't care about the date. Is there a workaround to just include time? Thanks! The Y-M-D portion of the result could be today's date.

Comment: If you're converting between time zones the date is important (as you've seen this impacts how many hours to add/subtract). If you care about the difference in time zones on the current day, then you could add today's date into the `as_datetime()` line.

Comment: Great!  this modification worked : `local_time <- force_tz(as_datetime(as.integer(as_datetime(Sys.Date()))+minutes_from_midnight*60), tzone = "America/Chicago")` . Thanks @nrennie

Answer (score 0):

The issue is to do with the Unix Epoch, and timezones (see nrennie's comments).

Here's a simplified version of the answer OP gave in the comments:

```
library(magrittr)

Sys.Date() %>%
  as_datetime() %>%
  {.+ (minutes_from_midnight*60)} %>% 
  force_tz(tzone = "America/Chicago")
```